# Historical lock for "Why does Java have the reputation of being slow?"

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

[Is Java really slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163411/why-does-java-have-the-reputation-of-being-slow) has 150 upvotes and 24K views. It has a top answer with 198 votes.

It has been closed, reopened, closed, deleted, undeleted, and now has 6 pending delete votes.

Given the scores, the post seems worth keeping. I think it meets the [criteria for a historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/historical-lock/info):

> 1 The post is Off-Topic or Not Constructive, and
>
> 2 The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, and
>
> 3 There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, and
>
> 4 The post is contentious; i.e. it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once

The top answer has been edited once in 2013 to bring it more up to date, so there may be some scope for a wiki lock instead, but it feels to me like a very slowly changing topic and I'd argue for just freezing it and being done with it.

Comment: wiki-lock? No, certainly not. Histo-lock seems reasonable, if we consider the answers valuable. Even though most suffer from the expected partisan viewpoints, that's surprisingly reasonable enough.

Comment: I'd rather see a wiki lock than a historical lock. We can improve a question with a wiki lock. We can't with a historical lock.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Evidence seems to suggest it won't be updated further. Do you think that will change?

Comment: Why is it being deleted?? :/ I don't understand.

Comment: I don't think this post needs to be locked with a historical lock because it's not significant in keeping - the post is not stellar and is not likely to help future readers other than conveying redundant information, which is likely obsolete par revision changes anyway. To be more specific, later versions of Java isn't even slow anymore, as mentioned in the answers itself.

Comment: The question contained a bunch of useless noise, which made it look worse than it actually is. Now removed.

Comment: Are you suggesting it shouldn't be even closed? I think it definitely should be, it's way too broad/opinion based.

Comment: Yeah I completely agree this would be a candidate for a historical lock. Going by Jeff Atwood's [We hate fun here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), even though the question doesn't match the criteria for the site, it definitely is accepted by the community looking at the upvotes and it teaches me something about Java (at least it's history). Leaving it protected might bring back the same noise @Jean-FrançoisCorbett just removed.

Comment: I don't feel this question provides information that could be potentially interesting in the future. Java evolves a lot and anything written there might already be totally off.

Comment: I don't see how the question *can* be formatted in such a way that it won't be subjective or opinion-based.  A lot of the answers in there are crap, and could be culled out.  I'm not going to vote to delete it again, because apparently enough high-reppers feel it needs to stick around, but it's just going to ping-pong back and forth between open and closed until people lose interest in fighting over it, or a moderator steps in.

Comment: I flagged it to begin with for historical lock and was sent to meta to get community consensus. How do I/we actually establish what that is? :-)

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam - the moderator actually declined your flag and said "Go to Meta?"

Comment: Marked it as helpful and said go to meta: "helpful - Please post a discussion post on Meta to ask for a historical lock to get community consensus."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a great candidate for a historical lock.  Yes, Java is constantly evolving and *some* of the information contained in the answers may become out of date, but the nature of the question is looking at Java's history - why has Java historically been considered slow?  The answers to that question *don't* change, and they are very well enumerated in the accepted answer.

Also, it's a question that a newer Java developer *will* likely run into and it's valuable for them to understand these things.

The rest of the accepted answer could never be complete, but that certainly does not mean it doesn't hold its own value.  More to the point, the key element to take away from this answer is that Java *is* evolving and improving over time, so any criticism should be evaluated against the current state of affairs.

Comment: Actually, the answer to the question "why has X historically been considered slow" assumes that it's no longer true. Or at least not or no longer based on facts. Someone made that pre-question obvious now. And the top answers make a bad job of answering that previously implied question, respectively assume things must be done the way they must be done in Java in any case.

Comment: I disagree that newer java developer would lkely run into this and even if they do, they will unlikely need a now really bad SO question to answer that.

Comment: Up until Peter did his edit-posts-to-link-random-nouns-to-Wikipedia thing he does, the question was only barely updated in 2010 and 2013. Moderators have even reversed community decision and unilaterally closed it. Under the most-upvoted-and-accepted-answer, under the category "A couple of other historical facts contributed to the "Java is slow" reputation", are gems such as Swing is just awful. The whole thing boils down to one person's opinion, and people are fighting to keep this thing open? I don't get it. I'm all for historical lock, or anything more severe than that.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau - what is so bad about the question that doesn't boil down to it being off-topic or opinion-based (neither point being in contention - indeed both points practically being prerequisites for a historical lock)?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - of course it's opinion.  It's opinion that counters an opinion, namely the opinion that Java is slow, an opinion that persists among those whose exposure to Java has only been tangential over the years.  The value of the opinions to the community can be measured by the upvotes and views

Comment: Nothing is stellar in the question or answers. Before the links were added, there wasn't many at all. It got a lot of views and votes but I would bet those mainly were from back then. There's no information worth keeping in it. Seriously, you think reading that question actually provide you with any useful information about a pseudo-rumor that java is slow? I can agree swing is rather sloppy but that doesn't define Java as slow or not. There's no piece of information in there worth keeping. Being an opinion is not a criteria for a historical lock.

Comment: I'm not a Java dev.  I held the opinion that Java was slow, mainly due to experience over a decade old, until about a year ago when I started to re-evaluate the current state of affairs.  I never saw this post before, but I learned some stuff about *how* Java had changed since I'd originally formed my opinion.  So, yes, I think the answer is useful.